# How to build a Postgres extension using cgo

Tags: postgresql, gcc, go, makefile, cgo

Here is what I'm doing right now,

```
.
├── helloworld--1.0.sql
├── helloworld.control
├── helloworld.go
└── Makefile
```

`helloworld.go` :

```
package helloworld

/*
#cgo LDFLAGS: -rdynamic
#include "postgres.h"
#include "fmgr.h"
#include "utils/builtins.h"

PG_MODULE_MAGIC;

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(helloworld);
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(hello_text_arg);
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(hello_ereport);

Datum
hello_world(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    PG_RETURN_TEXT_P(cstring_to_text("Hello, World!"));
}

Datum
hello_text_arg(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    text *hello     = cstring_to_text("Hello, ");
    int32 hello_sz  = VARSIZE(hello) - VARHDRSZ;

    text *name      = PG_GETARG_TEXT_P(0);
    int32 name_sz   = VARSIZE(name) - VARHDRSZ;

    text *tail      = cstring_to_text("!");
    int32 tail_sz   = VARSIZE(tail) - VARHDRSZ;

    int32 out_sz    = hello_sz + name_sz + tail_sz + VARHDRSZ;
    text *out       = (text *) palloc(out_sz);

    SET_VARSIZE(out, out_sz);

    memcpy(VARDATA(out), VARDATA(hello), hello_sz);
    memcpy(VARDATA(out) + hello_sz, VARDATA(name), name_sz);
    memcpy(VARDATA(out) + hello_sz + name_sz, VARDATA(tail), tail_sz);

    PG_RETURN_TEXT_P(out);
}

Datum
hello_ereport(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    ereport(ERROR, (errcode(ERRCODE_NULL_VALUE_NOT_ALLOWED), errmsg("null value not allowed")));

    PG_RETURN_VOID();
}
*/
import "C"
```

`Makefile` :

```
MODULES = helloworld

EXTENSION = helloworld
DATA = helloworld--1.0.sql
PGFILEDESC = "helloworld - example extension for postgresql"

REGRESS = helloworld

PG_CONFIG = pg_config
PGXS := $(shell $(PG_CONFIG) --pgxs)
INCLUDEDIR = $(shell $(PG_CONFIG) --includedir-server)
include $(PGXS)

helloworld.so:
    CGO_CFLAGS="-rdynamic -I$(INCLUDEDIR)" CGO_LDFLAGS="-rdynamic $(LDFLAGS)" go build -v -buildmode=c-shared -o helloworld.so .
```

It produced these errors when making :

```
/tmp/go-build019341122/github.com/amosbird/rpctest/helloworld/_obj/helloworld.cgo2.o: In function `hello_world':
helloworld.cgo2.c:(.text+0x48): undefined reference to `cstring_to_text'
/tmp/go-build019341122/github.com/amosbird/rpctest/helloworld/_obj/helloworld.cgo2.o: In function `hello_text_arg':
helloworld.cgo2.c:(.text+0x63): undefined reference to `cstring_to_text'
helloworld.cgo2.c:(.text+0x86): undefined reference to `pg_detoast_datum'
helloworld.cgo2.c:(.text+0xa5): undefined reference to `cstring_to_text'
helloworld.cgo2.c:(.text+0xd7): undefined reference to `palloc'
/tmp/go-build019341122/github.com/amosbird/rpctest/helloworld/_obj/helloworld.cgo2.o: In function `hello_ereport':
helloworld.cgo2.c:(.text+0x1a8): undefined reference to `errstart'
helloworld.cgo2.c:(.text+0x1bd): undefined reference to `errmsg'
helloworld.cgo2.c:(.text+0x1c9): undefined reference to `errcode'
helloworld.cgo2.c:(.text+0x1d7): undefined reference to `errfinish'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [helloworld.so] Error 2
```

I have no idea if this would work. There are so many black magic happened here.

So the main question is, *what is the correct Makefile that can be used to build a Postgres extension in cgo?*

A specific question to these errors is, *what can I do to defer those symbol resolution in cgo's linking process?*

Comment: Maybe look at how this CGO based library does it? https://github.com/jgallagher/go-libpq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I spent a whole day and found a viable solution.

We need to have the extension's main source file start with:

```
package main  // make sure to use main package

/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -I/path/to/postgres/include/server
#cgo LDFLAGS: -Wl,-unresolved-symbols=ignore-all
```

Use `go build -o myext.so -buildmode=c-shared myext.go` to generate `myext.so`.

If some Go method is needed from the C side, we should add `//export methodname` above the method declaration. This will generate symbols without package name prefix. Then we can extern these symbols on the C side. Make sure the exported Go methods reside in packages other than main.

`package test` :

```
//export Merge
func Merge(cint C.int) C.int ...
```

`package main` :

```
extern int Merge(int);

import "./test"
var _ = test.Somevar  // dumb placeholder to fake use package test.
```